# Get Path of Images from a Firefox Add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there anyway to find the file path of images being showed to user in web page , or anyway to find them ?

I want source code/programming .

Comment: You are programming a Firefox add-on? Is this correct? Just to confirm.

Comment: @Pekka : Yes , I need your help to create my software .

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `src` attribute of the image tag in question if its in the html. Otherwise you have to check the computed css for the text `url` in the `background` and `background-image` rules.

Comment: To do this for all images on the page, loop over all the elements in `doc.getElementsByTagName('img')`